# Compiling a c++ project in VS 2013 that is meant to compile in VS 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2008, compilation, libraries

I'm trying to edit an old open source project, but the project's README says that it was compiled in Visual Studio C++ 2008.  I don't have the money to buy 2008, but I do have a copy of Visual Studio C++ 2013.  I want to build this program on my machine so I can modify it.

Is there an easy way to do it?  Should this work on its own, or will certain code crash or have problems because of incompatibilities?

Also, the project mentions it requires some libraries. Do I need legacy versions of those libraries, or would modern versions work? (Specifically it uses MFC and DirectX SDK).

Comment: I think you're better off just trying it. Open the project in VS2013, it'll ask you to convert the project to VS2013. Then deal with one problem at a time (if any). The general case is that it works, but there are thousands of reasons why it might not, depending on what 3. party libraries the code is using, what part of MFC it's using, what part of C++ it's using, what part of microsoft specific APIs that might be deprecated or changed etc. There are way too many variables to make a laundry list of what should/shouldn't work and what to do about them.

Comment: What about the libraries?  Do you think I would need older versions of them, or would modern libraries work?

Comment: @user3760657 : The latest versions of the dependencies may be patched to resolve the bug in the preceding counterparts and may have slight or big improvements. That said,  it is always better to try and see what you get.